# Communication protocol between Telegram client and Telegram server

Tags: telegram

I want to make a simple Telegram client program that does a little operations, such as joining channels and so on.

I considered the Telegram API and its methods.

For the first step after I got api_id, hash_id and the public key, I should obtain the auth_key. I understood which data we should send to Telegram server and how to process the response data given from it. but the main question is that by what protocol we must organize our request data and parse the response?
How to send method name and the parameters to Telegram server? (especially for obtaining auth_key)

Comment: Your question is a little too vague to me. Are you using javascript? If yes, I highly recommend you to use this module: https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/ So you don't have to worry that much about interfacing your code with Telegram api's directly.

Answer (score -2):

You basically have two options:
- Long Polling
- Webhooks

The easiest one to start is long polling - it will allow you to debug your bot locally without the need to set up a real server.

I've written an article about bot in 30 lines of code with long polling with node.js; it might help you https://chatbotsmagazine.com/telegram-bot-with-node-js-in-30-lines-of-code-15504bf44a1f

For production - it depends.
I can't say there is some winner; you should understand the difference between the protocols first. But actually, there is no problem to deploy with long polling on the first steps either.